# ACF Multiple Checboxes Output

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to make FAQ's section using ACF. FAQ's will have categories which are checkboxes. I know how to output all FAQ's but I don't know how to output FAQ's based on checkbox.

Here's the code

```
<section>
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="small-12 cell section_header"><h2 class="section_title text-center">Frequently Asked Questions</h2></div>
<ul class="thin accordion faq" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true">
<?php if ( have_rows( 'faq', 'option' ) ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'faq', 'option' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
            <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
                <a href="#" class="accordion-title"><?php the_sub_field( 'faq_title' ); ?></a>
                <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content><?php the_sub_field( 'faq_answer' ); ?></div>
            </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand how this looks on the backend.
Also does it needs to look like it's checkboxes, or are you trying to group them in some way?